# MYSQL Return output of dates given a comparison using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, comparison

I have two tables: 
1) BUYnSELL, 2) STOCK

```
ticker | buy_or_sell | date       | price | num_of_shares |
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------+--
| IBM  | BUY         | 2019-03-20 | 273.0 | 1100          |
| IBM  | BUY         | 2019-03-21 | 271.0 | 2400          |
| IBM  | SELL        | 2019-03-22 | 270.5 | 2500          |
| GOOG | BUY         | 2019-03-20 | 86.0  | 2200          |
| GOOG | SELL        | 2019-03-20 | 87.0  |1000           |
| GOOG | SELL        | 2019-03-21 | 87.5  |1000           |
| GOOG | BUY         | 2019-03-21 | 87.0  | 800           |
| GOOG | SELL        | 2019-03-22 | 86.0  | 1000          |
| AAPL | BUY         | 2019-03-20 | 99.0  |1000           |
| AAPL | BUY         | 2019-03-20 | 99.5  | 1000          |
| AAPL | BUY         | 2019-03-21 | 100.0 |1000           |
| AAPL | SELL        | 2019-03-22 | 103.0 |3000           |
| MSFT | BUY         | 2019-03-20 | 186.0 | 1500          |
| MSFT | SELL        | 2019-03-21 | 188.0 |1000           |
| MSFT | BUY         | 2019-03-22 | 187.0 |5000           |

| ticker | exchange |
+--------+----------+
| AAPL   | NASDAQ   |
| GOOG   | NASDAQ   |
| MSFT   | NASDAQ   |
| IBM    | NYSE     |
| UNH    | NYSE     |
```

And I want to find the dates where: the price*number of shares of 'AAPL' where buy_or_sell = SELL was higher than what the firm bought (buy_or_sell = BUY) in 'NASDAQ'. I don't want to use any natural joins.

I have the queries that achieve this but I don't know how to properly combine them. So I have:

```
SELECT distinct A.date, A.ticker, SUM(A.price*A.num_of_shares) AS ‘TOTAL’ 
FROM BUYnSELL A, STOCK S 
WHERE A.ticker='AAPL' AND A.buy_or_sell = 'SELL' AND A.ticker = S.ticker 
GROUP BY A.date, A.ticker;
```

^this returns the dates, ticker, and total price*number of shares for apple only

And this:

```
SELECT distinct B.date, SUM(B.price*B.num_of_shares) AS 'BTOTAL' 
FROM BUYnSELL B, STOCK T 
WHERE B.ticker = T.ticker AND B.buy_or_sell = 'BUY' AND T.exchange = 'NASDAQ'
GROUP BY B.date, B.ticker;
```

^this returns the dates and total price*number of shares for anything bought in NASDAQ only

Does anyone know how I can combine these two queries so it will return the dates when the total in the first one is greater than the values given in the second query?

So, only date 2019-03-22 should return because the value apple sold that day is higher than any of the values that the second query returns.

New to SQL and any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite simple way:

```
select A.date from BUYnSELL as A, STOCK as B  
   where A.ticker = B.ticker 
   group by A.ticker, A.date
   having 
      sum(
         if(A.buy_or_sell='SELL' AND A.ticker = 'AAPL', 1,
         if(A.buy_or_sell='BUY' AND B.exchange = 'NASDAQ',-1,0)) 
         * A.price * A.num_of_shares) > 0;
```

Basically: if it is "SELL" and "APPLE", you multiply by 1 (add). If it is "BUY" and "NASDAQ", you multiply by -1 (subtract). Otherwise, multiply by 0 (doesn't do anything).

At the end, you only take the positive values, i.e., the ones where SELL is bigger than BUY.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `conditional aggregation` :

```
SELECT A.date, A.ticker, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN A.buy_or_sell = 'SELL' AND A.ticker='AAPL' THEN 
                      A.price*A.num_of_shares
            END ) TOTAL_SELL,                  
       SUM( CASE WHEN A.buy_or_sell = 'BUY' AND S.exchange = 'NASDAQ' THEN
                      A.price*A.num_of_shares 
            END ) AS TOTAL_BUY
  FROM BUYnSELL A
  JOIN STOCK S ON S.ticker = A.ticker 
 GROUP BY A.date, A.ticker;
```

P.S. Prefer using `ANSI-92` join syntax rather than `ANSI-89` syntax which has comma-seperated tables list. That's easier to read and understand.